# Когда 'cursor = conn.cursor()' лучше, чем 'with conn.cursor() as curs:'?

Tags: python, postgresql, инспекция-кода, psycopg2

Сейчас есть 2 запроса:

- выбрать сообщения которые надо отправить юзеру (пройтись по юзерам циклом)
- обновить номер последнего отправленного сообщения юзеру

Будет еще 3й запрос:

- выбрать из БД users юзеров которым надо отправить сообщение сегодня.

Подразумевается, что все запросы будут в одной функции.

Вопрос: не лучше ли в этом случае использовать не `with conn.cursor() as curs:`,
а `cursor = conn.cursor()`, ведь в таком случае можно один раз создать курсор и держать его открытым пока функция не закончит работать?

Спасибо!

Код:

```py
# создаю курсор для селект запроса
with conn.cursor() as curs:
    # создаю запрос выборки таблицы
    query = '''SELECT users.user_id_tg as user_tg_id,
                        interest_1.msg_text as msg_interest_1,
                        interest_2.msg_text as msg_interest_2,
                        interest_3.msg_text as msg_interest_3,
                        interest_4.msg_text as msg_interest_4,
                        interest_5.msg_text as msg_interest_5
                FROM interest_1_t, interest_2_t, interest_3_t, interest_4_t, interest_5_t, users
                WHERE (interest_1_t.msg_id > users.interest_1
                        AND interest_2_t.msg_id > users.interest_2
                        AND interest_3_t.msg_id > users.interest_3
                        AND interest_4_t.msg_id > users.interest_4
                        AND interest_5_t.msg_id > users.interest_5)
                    AND users.user_id_tg = %s
                LIMIT 1'''
    # отправить запрос в бд
    curs.execute(query, (x_user,))
    # вернуть результат запроса
    out = curs.fetchone()
    print(out)

# создаю курсор для апдейт запроса
with conn.cursor() as curs:
    # создаю запрос обновления таблицы
    query = '''UPDATE users
                SET interest_1 =
                    CASE WHEN interest_1 > 0
                    THEN interest_1 + 1 ELSE interest_1
                    END,
                    interest_2 =
                    CASE WHEN interest_2 > 0
                    THEN interest_2 + 1 ELSE interest_2
                    END,
                    interest_3 =
                    CASE WHEN interest_3 > 0
                    THEN interest_3 + 1 ELSE interest_3
                    END,
                    interest_4 =
                    CASE WHEN interest_4 > 0
                    THEN interest_4 + 1 ELSE interest_4
                    END,
                    interest_5 =
                    CASE WHEN interest_5 > 0
                    THEN interest_5 + 1 ELSE interest_5
                    END,
                    next_date_push = CURRENT_DATE + f_push
                WHERE user_id_tg = %s'''
    # отправить запрос в бд
    curs.execute(query, (x_user,))
    # сохранить результат запроса
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: не лучше. а что мешает вам один раз создать курсор с помощью контент-менеджера with?

Comment: Так и хотел. Но когда я удаляю второй 'with conn.cursor() as curs:' для запроса на обновление таблицы, то запрос перестает работать.

Comment: он перестает работать с ошибкой или просто "ничего не делает"? если второй вариант, могу посоветовать после первого запроса попробовать сделать `conn.commit()`.

Comment: Разобрался. После того как дописал третий запрос удалил лишний к-менеджер и вылезла ошибка несогласованности отступов и пробелов. Поковырялся и заработало.